# Javascript and CSS Embed into HTML Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm a bit new here, so please do correct me if I do anything wrong.

Basically I am try to create a "task table" where, in addition to being able to edit the tasks to their consent, users can add more tasks. I have programmed a bit of the table (and thank you to Ash Blue for the base template), but I have run into some problems.

First, if you hover over the stop or pause buttons, you will see that the buttons to the left of them will also have the effect. Next, the "add task" and "export task" buttons aren't working. This is they are supposed to work: [CodePen.](http://codepen.io/jeffersonyu1/pen/WGPpxX)
Lastly, I have not coded this yet, but the "start/time" time boxes on the extra rows need to have different variables, otherwise when the start button is clicked on one row, all of the stopwatches for all the rows will start. Sorry this is not too clear, but if you don't get it I will try to explain it in more detail.

This is the current code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js"></script>

<script>
var $TABLE = $('#table');
var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
var $EXPORT = $('#export');

$('.table-add').click(function() {
  var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');
  $TABLE.find('table').append($clone);
});

$('.table-remove').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$('.table-up').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if ($row.index() === 1) return; // Don't go above the header
  $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$('.table-down').click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.click(function() {
  var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
  var headers = [];
  var data = [];

  // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
  $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function() {
    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
  });

  // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).find('td');
    var h = {};

    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();
    });

    data.push(h);
  });

  // Output the result
  $EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));
});
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Assignment Name</th>
        <th>Start / End</th>
        <th>Time Elapsed</th>
        <th>Suggested Time</th>
        <th>Controls</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Geometry</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Start / End</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">Elapsed</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">25 min</td>
        <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play play">
              <span class="
glyphicon glyphicon-pause pause">

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop stop">

        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span><span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>

        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
      <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button id="export-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data</button>
  <p id="export"></p>
</div>

<style>
.table-editable {
  position: relative;
}
.table-editable .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table-remove {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-remove:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.table-up, .table-down {
  color: #007;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-up:hover, .table-down:hover {
  color: #00f;
}

.table-add {
  color: #070;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}
.table-add:hover {
  color: #0b0;
}

.play {
  color: #209E00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.play:hover {
  color: #5FCF00;
}

.pause {
  color: #F17400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pause:hover {
  color: #FF9E01;
}

.stop {
  color: #700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.stop:hover, span.stop:active {
  color: #f00;
}
</style>
```

If I do encounter any problems with this same table in the future, do I just post another question? Or should I just edit this post?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to close the span tags:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play play"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause pause"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop stop"></span>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that. Could you guide me on the other two problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think the other two buttons are working fine. May be your hidden tr should look like this?

```
<tr class="hide">
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"></td>
    <td>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play play"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause pause"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop stop"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="table-up glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
      <span class="table-down glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
      <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that (I just haven't had the time to make that edit). I think the error in my second question is that the script src isn't working.